# Redux call dispatch from Socketio event

Tags: javascript, redux, socket.io

I am trying to call a dispatch in my action when I receive a socket.io event.

AppActions.js:

```
export const _ioDispatch = (data) => (dispatch, getState ) => {
  console.log("_ioDispatch")
  dispatch(data);
}

socket.on('item created', function(payload){
  console.log("socket on item created")
  _ioDispatch(payload);
});
```

I get the console log "socket on item created" but the console log "_ioDispatch" and dispatch never get called.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: `_ioDispatch(payload);` is returning a function, it is not supposed to call it.

Comment: @Logar not sure what you mean. The dispatch never gets called either

Comment: I tried to give it a shot, tell me if it's ok for you

Comment: Well, what I mean is that with the chunk of code you give, there is no reason to believe that the function returned by `_ioDispatch(payload)`  ever gets called, so obviously there will be no `console.log('_ioDispatch')` and no `dispatch(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about your implementation but I will assume you have some connected React component in which you attach your socket. What you need is to dispatch the _ioDispatch(payload) so that it reaches `redux` and the `redux-thunk` (or whichever you use) middleware. Something like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class MyComponent extends React.component {
    constructor(props) {
        //create socket and do stuff here..
        socket.on('item created', function(payload){
            console.log("socket on item created")
            props.socketCallback(payload);
        });
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
   socketCallback: (payload) => dispatch(_ioDispatch(payload))
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

And by the way, if your _ioDispatch function is just as you describe :

```
export const _ioDispatch = (data) => (dispatch, getState ) => {
    console.log("_ioDispatch")
    dispatch(data);
}
```

Then you could simply remove it and change mapDispatchToProps to :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
   socketCallback: (payload) => dispatch(payload)
});
```

Comment: thanks! I was looking for a way to do it from within the action, but I have implemented your solution and it works